# Python and OpenGL performance improvement

Tags: python, opengl, arguments

I am currently learning OpenGL by using the Python bindings. I wrote some code that effectively does something like this

```
def draw():
    background(35)
    for x in range(50):
        for y in range(50):
            fill(random(), 1.0, 1.0)
            rect(x, y, random(), random())
```

Essentially, I am drawing a grid of 2500 rectangles with different width, heights, and fill colors.

It seems that it takes about **40 ms** to execute a **single call** to `draw()`.

The way I draw the objects is what I believe to be non-modern OpenGL:

`rect(x, y, w, h)` is simply a call to `glRectf(x, y, x + w, y + h)`.

`fill(r, g, b)` is a call to `glColor3f(r, g, b)`.

Double buffering is not being used and, lastly, the main loop looks something like this:

```
while True:
    draw()
    glutSwapBuffers()
```

Now, I am wondering why is `draw()` so slow?

## My attempts at diagnosing/fixing the issue:

I read online and eventually found myself believing that the issue lied in the fact that I was not using VBOs/VAOs, and all of the calls to the GPU were useless since I call `glRectf` on every rectangle, as opposed to having one main draw call to the GPU.

I am unsure if building up an array of vertices is still to slow. So, before I go about refactoring a lot of code, I am wondering if it is likely that this is the actual problem. That is, is it likely that the bottleneck are too many draw calls to the GPU, and that I should instead use VBOs to build up a huge array of vertices and do one draw call to the GPU at the end of `draw`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 2500 is a lot of draw calls in contrast to what you're drawing.

> The way I draw the objects is what I believe to be non-modern OpenGL

You are correct.

Calling `glRect(x1, y1, x2, y2)` is the equivalent of doing:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex2(x1, y1);
glVertex2(x2, y1);
glVertex2(x2, y2);
glVertex2(x1, y2);
glEnd();
```

Which is referred to as immediate mode.

> I am wondering if it is likely that this is the actual problem.

Again, you are correct. Considering you're essentially using `glBegin()` / `glEnd(...)` 2500 times. That's a lot of commands as well as data spread over 2500 *draw calls*.

The only reason vertex arrays and a vertex buffer would be slower. Was if you were to equally call `glDrawArray()` 2500 times (considering you also update the buffers each time).

> that I should instead use VBOs to build up a huge array of vertices and do one draw call to the GPU at the end of draw

The general rule of thumb is to do as few OpenGL calls and as few state changes as possible.

Considering that you're talking about 2500 rectangles (or 5000 triangles). That's still a lot of triangles to draw in the first place, when you have to update them each frame.

Would a single `glBufferData()` and `glDrawArrays()` be faster than 2500 `glBegin()` / `glEnd(...)` each frame? Possibly. However it might be faster to have a couple of buffers. The reason being that the CPU and GPU are asynchronous. So while you're building your big array of vertices, the GPU could already be drawing some of them while you're building the next part. That would most definitely be faster.

Last but not least, I'm not advocating the use of immediate mode (`glBegin()` / `glEnd(...)`). The point I'm trying to make is that 1 `glDrawArray()` could be slower than 10 `glDrawArray()`, in contrast to your problem. While CPU is updating the next 500 triangles, the GPU could be drawing the first 500 triangles, instead of waiting until all of them can be drawn.

Bottom line is of course to try each solution and benchmark.

Comment: Okay! What I will likely do is have a list of vertices and every time it fills with `n` entries, I'll call `glDrawArrays()`. I'll see how well that works. Thanks!